# Connection terminated while importing SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, import

I'm trying to import a PostgreSQL file with node code.
Problem is that it starts well everything is importing but in 20 seconds am getting errors

**Error executing query 6814: Error: Connection terminated**

How I searched it may be because of the timeout limit but I added a timeout to 1 min but am still getting the same error...

Can someone help me with this problem please...

```
client.query('DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public;', (e, res) => {
  console.log(e, res)
  client.end()
})

exec('node ace migration:run', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`)
    return
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    return
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
})

////////////////////
client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('connection error', err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log('connected')

    // read the .sql file
    const sql = fs.readFileSync(`${DBDir}/TEST_DB.sql`).toString()

    // split the SQL file into individual queries
    const queries = sql.split(';')

    // run each query sequentially
    queries.forEach((query, index) => {
      console.log(`Executing query ${index}: ${query}`)
      client.query(query, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error executing query ${index}: ${err.stack}`)
        } else {
          console.log(`Query ${index} executed successfully`)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

So first am dropping schema public, then creating schema public, then running migrations, and after that am trying to import DB.

Comment: What can you see in the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: Hello, Now am getting new errors,  Error executing query 1846: error: syntax error at or near "mso"
Error executing query 1854: error: syntax error at or near "line"

Comment: Nice for you. But how can we help with that if you give us no information?